# Weird Bigram Issue

Tags: python

I am working with bigrams and I have a question. I have the right answer but in the wrong format

```
import nltk
import collections
import collections
from collections import defaultdict

cnt = collections.Counter()

tokens = [['a','b','c','d'],['b','c','a','b','c']]

def bigram(tokens, n):
    for toks in tokens:
        cnt.update(nltk.bigrams(toks))

    return cnt.most_common(n)

print bigram(tokens, 2)
```

I was able to to get the right output: `[(('b', 'c'), 3), (('a', 'b'), 2)]`
but I need it to be `[(('b c'), 3), (('a b'), 2)]`. I asked the professor if I could rearrange the parameters but he insisted that the input must be `bigram(tokens, n)` to get full credit.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
return [(" ".join(tup), count) for tup, count in cnt.most_common(n)]
```

That will impress your prof with list comprehensions, elegant handling of tuples, and length-ignorant joining of tuples :D

By the way, I always recommend being honest -- so you might want to say "someone on the internet gave me this hint, but I can understand why this works" -- that way you'll never be accountable for plagiarism, and would be prepared for possible exams.

Comment: Don't write his homework. He will not learn anything that way.

Comment: @user38034: His prof will be smart enough to use google on his very few lines of code, and will wind up here; google really is no plagiator's friend. I trust Datguyovrder to be clever enough to actually try to understand what I wrote -- otherwise, his Prof is *bound* to notice, because obviously if someone comes along trying to get his non-compliant solution through, but suddenly comes up with a proper one, you start asking questions like "how does that work?".

Comment: I think that professors have more important things to do than to google some code of his students.

Comment: I don't think examiners have a hard time guessing which students understand their code and who just copies together their stuff.